# Opening, randomizing, writing a list of lines in Python 2.7.6.1

Tags: python, random

I want to take a large list of vocabulary words (each word + definition is a line), randomize the list, and then write it a file in 142 item blocks without repeating any words.

I think I'm roughly close, but the writing lines back is giving me trouble.  Here's what I have:

```
import random
zz = 0
with open('vocablist.text') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('vocablist.txt')]
random.shuffle(lines)
vocab_out = open('vocab_out.txt.', 'w')
for x in lines:
    zz = zz +1
    if zz > 142:
        vocab_out.write('END OF SECTION'+\n)
        zz = 0
    vocab_out.write(x)
vocab_out.close()
```

I have to re-make these vocab lists for a class I took over and doing it by hand would take me days.

Comment: You need to specify what is wrong with the code you posted. What does "giving me trouble" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
import random

with\
  open('vocablist.text') as input,\
  open('vocab_out.txt', 'w') as output:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in input.readlines()]
    random.shuffle(lines)
    zz = 0
    for x in lines:
      zz += 1
      if zz > 142:
          output.write('END OF SECTION' + '\n')
          zz = 0
      output.write(x + '\n')
```

The changes:

1. `for line in open` to `for line in input.readlines()`
2. `with` for both files so they're opened and closed together.
3. The `\n` in `+\n` needed to be quoted as a string
4. Added a `+ '\n'` to the `output.write`

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.  You've just saved me literally days of copying and pasting by hand, thank you so much!